# Crash errors from apache

Tags: apache-2.2, debian

> (none):~# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart Restarting web server: apache2
>   reboot  ... waiting (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not
>   bind to address [::]:80 (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could
>   not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available,
>   shutting down Unable to open logs  failed! (none):~#

On debian, anyone have any idea what that means?

EDIT:

**lsof -i**

```
COMMAND     PID     USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE NODE NAME
portmap    1926   daemon    4u  IPv4    4615       UDP *:sunrpc
portmap    1926   daemon    5u  IPv4    4621       TCP *:sunrpc (LISTEN)
rpc.statd  1937    statd    5u  IPv4    4647       UDP *:841
rpc.statd  1937    statd    7u  IPv4    4658       UDP *:36239
rpc.statd  1937    statd    8u  IPv4    4661       TCP *:41621 (LISTEN)
named      2174     bind   20u  IPv6    5186       TCP *:domain (LISTEN)
named      2174     bind   21u  IPv4    5189       TCP localhost:domain (LISTEN)
named      2174     bind   22u  IPv4    5191       TCP ns1.**********.com:domain (LI            STEN)
named      2174     bind   23u  IPv4    5193       TCP ns2.**********.com:domain (LI            STEN)
named      2174     bind   24u  IPv4    5195       TCP customer.worldstream.nl:d            omain (LISTEN)
named      2174     bind   25u  IPv4    5196       TCP localhost:953 (LISTEN)
named      2174     bind   26u  IPv6    5197       TCP localhost:953 (LISTEN)
named      2174     bind  512u  IPv6    5185       UDP *:domain
named      2174     bind  513u  IPv4    5188       UDP localhost:domain
named      2174     bind  514u  IPv4    5190       UDP ns1.**********.com:domain
named      2174     bind  515u  IPv4    5192       UDP ns2.**********.com:domain
named      2174     bind  516u  IPv4    5194       UDP customer.worldstream.nl:d            omain
lwresd     2192     root  512u  IPv4    5233       UDP localhost:921
sshd       2209     root    3u  IPv6    5260       TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd       2209     root    4u  IPv4    5262       TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
mysqld     2286    mysql   10u  IPv4    5358       TCP localhost:mysql (LISTEN)
master     2429     root   12u  IPv4    5661       TCP *:smtp (LISTEN)
dovecot    2456     root    5u  IPv4    5813       TCP *:imap2 (LISTEN)
dovecot    2456     root    6u  IPv4    5814       TCP *:imaps (LISTEN)
dovecot    2456     root    7u  IPv4    5815       TCP *:pop3 (LISTEN)
dovecot    2456     root    8u  IPv4    5816       TCP *:pop3s (LISTEN)
imap-logi  2497  dovecot    0u  IPv4    5813       TCP *:imap2 (LISTEN)
imap-logi  2497  dovecot    1u  IPv4    5814       TCP *:imaps (LISTEN)
imap-logi  2498  dovecot    0u  IPv4    5813       TCP *:imap2 (LISTEN)
imap-logi  2498  dovecot    1u  IPv4    5814       TCP *:imaps (LISTEN)
imap-logi  2499  dovecot    0u  IPv4    5813       TCP *:imap2 (LISTEN)
imap-logi  2499  dovecot    1u  IPv4    5814       TCP *:imaps (LISTEN)
apache2    2500     root    3u  IPv6    5933       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
pop3-logi 10494  dovecot    0u  IPv4    5815       TCP *:pop3 (LISTEN)
pop3-logi 10494  dovecot    1u  IPv4    5816       TCP *:pop3s (LISTEN)
pop3-logi 10495  dovecot    0u  IPv4    5815       TCP *:pop3 (LISTEN)
pop3-logi 10495  dovecot    1u  IPv4    5816       TCP *:pop3s (LISTEN)
pop3-logi 10496  dovecot    0u  IPv4    5815       TCP *:pop3 (LISTEN)
pop3-logi 10496  dovecot    1u  IPv4    5816       TCP *:pop3s (LISTEN)
apache2   12270 www-data    3u  IPv6    5933       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
apache2   12362 www-data    3u  IPv6    5933       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
apache2   12362 www-data   18u  IPv6 1819101       TCP ns1.**********.com:www->77.28            .128.86:1619 (CLOSE_WAIT)
apache2   12426 www-data    3u  IPv6    5933       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
apache2   12461 www-data    3u  IPv6    5933       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
apache2   12461 www-data   18u  IPv6 1818917       TCP ns1.**********.com:www->201-9            5-197-250.dsl.telesp.net.br:4479 (CLOSE_WAIT)
apache2   12482 www-data    3u  IPv6    5933       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
apache2   12484 www-data    3u  IPv6    5933       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
apache2   12484 www-data   18u  IPv6 1818866       TCP ns1.**********.com:www->crawl            -66-249-66-82.googlebot.com:52039 (CLOSE_WAIT)
apache2   12488 www-data    3u  IPv6    5933       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
apache2   12488 www-data   18u  IPv6 1819029       TCP ns1.**********.com:www->112.2            01.101.139.pldt.net:63010 (CLOSE_WAIT)
apache2   12497 www-data    3u  IPv6    5933       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
apache2   12497 www-data   18u  IPv6 1819271       TCP ns1.**********.com:www->218.1            86.8.12.cache.maxonline.com.sg:46939 (CLOSE_WAIT)
apache2   12498 www-data    3u  IPv6    5933       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
apache2   12508 www-data    3u  IPv6    5933       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
apache2   12508 www-data   18u  IPv6 1817510       TCP ns1.**********.com:www->27.11            4.163.5:39928 (CLOSE_WAIT)
apache2   12522 www-data    3u  IPv6    5933       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
apache2   12522 www-data   18u  IPv6 1818318       TCP ns1.**********.com:www->host-            78-149-249-247.as13285.net:10024 (CLOSE_WAIT)
apache2   12523 www-data    3u  IPv6    5933       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
apache2   12523 www-data   18u  IPv6 1818932       TCP ns1.**********.com:www->182.1            83.191.113:50494 (CLOSE_WAIT)
apache2   12975 www-data    3u  IPv6    5933       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
apache2   12975 www-data   18u  IPv6 1818501       TCP ns1.**********.com:www->120.1            8.250.170:52049 (CLOSE_WAIT)
apache2   12982 www-data    3u  IPv6    5933       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
apache2   12982 www-data   18u  IPv6 1818734       TCP ns1.**********.com:www->112.2            10.191.112.pldt.net:55611 (CLOSE_WAIT)
apache2   12987 www-data    3u  IPv6    5933       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
apache2   12987 www-data   18u  IPv6 1818472       TCP ns1.**********.com:www->122.5            4.221.45.pldt.net:61861 (CLOSE_WAIT)
apache2   12989 www-data    3u  IPv6    5933       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
apache2   12991 www-data    3u  IPv6    5933       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
apache2   12991 www-data   18u  IPv6 1819004       TCP ns1.**********.com:www->112.2            03.98.49.pldt.net:57522 (CLOSE_WAIT)
apache2   12997 www-data    3u  IPv6    5933       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
apache2   12997 www-data   18u  IPv6 1817901       TCP ns1.**********.com:www->113.2            2.112.193:3295 (CLOSE_WAIT)
apache2   12999 www-data    3u  IPv6    5933       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
apache2   12999 www-data   18u  IPv6 1818255       TCP ns1.**********.com:www->local            host:3314 (CLOSE_WAIT)
apache2   13001 www-data    3u  IPv6    5933       TCP *:www (LISTEN)
```

**netstat -tulpn| grep :80**

```
(none):~# netstat -tulpn| grep :80 tcp6 0 0 :::80 :::* LISTEN 2500/apache2
```

**killall -9 apache**

```
apache: no process killed
```

Comment: `lsof -i` - what's got port 80?

Answer (score 1):

Check what process is listening on :80:

```
netstat -tulpn| grep :80
```

Also check what is the path for logs (maybe additional for vhost) - does it exist? does apache has permissions to access?

Comment: I will check it next time it happens. I did a reboot and it got fixed. It crashes like everyweekend twice or more....

And Yes, I do have more Virtual hosts. Do you want me to post the log here?

Comment: You mentioned that it happens regularly... hm.. strange - especially if you can be sure that you are not issuing stop/start/restart etc. - but the restart can be caused by **logrotate** - it kills apache process (usually reloades - but look into init.d scruipt to see what indeed is reload), changes file and starts again - if there is strange process hunting for free 80 port - can have a chance then. But it will succeed always at the same hour - look into logrotate settings for apache.

Comment: this is what I get `(none):~# netstat -tulpn| grep :80
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2500/apache2
`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have something already working on port 80. Try to find any other webserver working on port 80, or manually kill all remaining apache (httpd) processes

```
killall -9 apache
```

On some systems the apache process may be running as httpd

Comment: @Salvomir `apache: no process killed`